# How to draw interlocking circle use canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawable

I have a issues that: i want to draw an olympic logo with 5 circle, but it need to interlocking with each others. Thanks
[image]

Not like this:
[image]

Comment: I just draw 5 circles. 2 circles draw on top 3 circles. But i want they interlocking with each others

Comment: Sorry, i updated description. Thanks sir for recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to draw an olympic logo is to use high quality png image.
But if it is inappropriate for you there is more harder way - you need to draw not circles on canvas, but arcs. You have to calculate all sizes for those arcs and scale them to fit your views.

Comment: But i think draw arcs is very complicated. In my case i need to calculate a lot of things :( Cicle is impossible?

Comment: yes, because of some of them have parts with different relative depth, but tou can't use different depth for one circle in canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at what you want then.

First, you'll need to create a custom View in order to override the `onDraw` method.

This is where you will draw your circles.

To draw a circle on a canvas, you will use

`drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)`

Where
  cx : position X of the center
  cy : position Y of the center
  radius : the radius of the circle
  paint : the paint you'll be using to draw your circle

Now for your paint, you'll just have to create a new one, set its color
  `paint.setColor(Color.RED)`
As well as the style of the paint : 
  `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke)`
Eventually the stroke width and other style you'd like to have.

With all of this, you should be able to work your way through what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. But I want they interlocking each others, your solutions just make them ON TOP each others

Comment: They won't as far as you provide a different `cx` and `cy` for each one of them

Comment: No, I mean they need to INTERLOCKING each others, I just edit the description, could you have a look again?

Comment: Oh, like one going over and under of the other ones? Then @evgenii is right, you'll need to calculate arcs and draw them in the right order

Comment: Yes, but drawing arcs is very complicated. Is circle impossible to do that?

Comment: Drawing on a canvas, each circle will be "on top of each other". Same principle if you were drawing it on a piece of paper. If you draw a circle, it's there, at a certain "elevation". Once it's there, you cannot draw under it, only over it. Therefore, if your desired output is to have them "over and under", you'll need to use arcs